# Plthook.elf.c throws undefined reference to 'dl_iterate_phdr'

Tags: android, java-native-interface

My compiling could not finish with ndk-build for a shared library for my android project, im using a library called plthook which can be found here: https://github.com/kubo/plthook

The file plthook_elf.c causes the error in line 282 in dl_iterate_phdr, see: https://github.com/kubo/plthook/blob/master/plthook_elf.c which calls up these errors:

jni/plthook/plthook_elf.c:282: error: undefined reference to 'dl_iterate_phdr'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libhello-jni.so] Error 1

Code at line 282:

```
dl_iterate_phdr(dl_iterate_cb, &data);
    if (data.lmap.l_ld == NULL) {
        set_errmsg("Could not find memory region containing address %p", address);
        return PLTHOOK_INTERNAL_ERROR;
    }
```

I thought i could build it but failed, so if there's a solution, please comment...

Comment: Is it solved now?